# Dynamic column position with specified anchor point

Tags: r, function, data.table

I want to make a function where I can specify which column should be the anchor point, or the basis of the calculations.

```
set.seed(123)
library(data.table)

dt = data.table(Acc_ID = c(1:50),
                P1 = sample((0:10000), 50, replace = T),
                P2 = sample((0:10000), 50, replace = T),
                P3 = sample((0:10000), 50, replace = T),
                P4 = sample((0:10000), 50, replace = T),
                P5 = sample((0:10000), 50, replace = T), 
                P6 = sample((0:10000), 50, replace = T),
                P7 = sample((0:10000), 50, replace = T), 
                P8 = sample((0:10000), 50, replace = T),
                P9 = sample((0:10000), 50, replace = T),
                P10 = sample((0:10000), 50, replace = T),
                P11 = sample((0:10000), 50, replace = T),
                P12 = sample((0:10000), 50, replace = T))
```

End result should look like this:

```
dt[, `:=` (sumcoll1m = `P12`,
           sumcoll3m = rowSums(dt[, `P10`:`P12`]),
           sumcoll6m = rowSums(dt[,  `P7`:`P12`]),
           sumcoll12m = rowSums(dt[,  `P1`:`P12`]),
           payments1m = ifelse(dt[, `P12`] > 0, 1, 0),
           payments3m = rowSums(dt[, `P10`:`P12`] > 0),
           payments6m = rowSums(dt[, `P7`:`P12`] > 0),
           payments12m = rowSums(dt[, `P1`:`P12`] > 0))]
```

In this example the anchor point is P12, but it could be whatever and it could also be a different name. What I would like is to have the same length of interval regardless of what the anchor point is - with the exception that if the anchor point is P1, then it would only do the calculations where it is applicable.

Is there a smart way to do this?

Thank you in advance!

Edit: Yes, it denotes months. Expected result for P5 would be:

```
dt[, `:=` (sumcoll1m = `P5`,
           sumcoll3m = rowSums(dt[, `P3`:`P5`]),
           payments1m = ifelse(dt[, `P5`] > 0, 1, 0),
           payments3m = rowSums(dt[, `P3`:`P5`] > 0))]
```

This is where I am at the moment:

```
dt[, `:=` (sumcoll1m = `P12`,
           sumcoll3m = rowSums(dt[, c(which(names(dt) == "P12") - seq(0, 2)), with = F]),
           sumcoll6m = rowSums(dt[,  c(which(names(dt) == "P12") - seq(0, 5)), with = F]),
           sumcoll12m = rowSums(dt[,  c(which(names(dt) == "P12") - seq(0, 11)), with = F]),
           payments1m = ifelse(dt[, `P12`] > 0, 1, 0),
           payments3m = rowSums(dt[, c(which(names(dt) == "P12") - seq(0, 2)), with = F] > 0),
           payments6m = rowSums(dt[, c(which(names(dt) == "P12") - seq(0, 5)), with = F] > 0),
           payments12m = rowSums(dt[, c(which(names(dt) == "P12") - seq(0, 11)), with = F] > 0))]
```

Comment: Have you considered to reshape from wide to long format?

Comment: @Uwe, thank you for your reply. I thought about it, but I do not think that would make the problem easier (correct me if I am wrong). I was thinking of something more in the line of using which function to determine the column id and then just subtract from that id to get the interval, but haven't figured it out yet.

Comment: Do the columns denote months? Just concluding from the number of P-columns. Also, please [edit] your Q and show the expected result for anchor point, e.g., P5 to make sure I fully understand your logic. Would `sumcoll6m` the row sums of columns P1 to P5, then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a tricky one. My suggestion is to reshape the data from wide to long form and to compute the aggregates on the variable lengths windows using `tail()`.

#### Minimal dataset for verification

But first, we need to define a minimal working dataset which helps to verify the correctness of the result:

```
library(data.table)
n_row <- 2
DT <- data.table(Acc_ID = seq_len(n_row))
for (i in 1:12) {
  set(DT, , paste0("P", i), (100*seq_len(n_row) + i) * (-1)^i)
}
DT
```

> ```
>    Acc_ID   P1  P2   P3  P4   P5  P6   P7  P8   P9 P10  P11 P12
> 1:      1 -101 102 -103 104 -105 106 -107 108 -109 110 -111 112
> 2:      2 -201 202 -203 204 -205 206 -207 208 -209 210 -211 212
> ```

#### Reshaping

```
long <- melt(DT, "Acc_ID")
long[, variable := as.ordered(variable)]
long
```

> ```
>     Acc_ID variable value
>  1:      1       P1  -101
>  2:      2       P1  -201
>  3:      1       P2   102
>  4:      2       P2   202
>  5:      1       P3  -103
>  6:      2       P3  -203
>  7:      1       P4   104
>  8:      2       P4   204
>  9:      1       P5  -105
> 10:      2       P5  -205
> 11:      1       P6   106
> 12:      2       P6   206
> 13:      1       P7  -107
> 14:      2       P7  -207
> 15:      1       P8   108
> 16:      2       P8   208
> 17:      1       P9  -109
> 18:      2       P9  -209
> 19:      1      P10   110
> 20:      2      P10   210
> 21:      1      P11  -111
> 22:      2      P11  -211
> 23:      1      P12   112
> 24:      2      P12   212
>     Acc_ID variable value
> ```

`variable` is already a factor with the levels in order of columns left to right. However, for comparing with the anchor point, `variable` has been turned into an `ordered factor`. By this, the columns can be arbitrarily named, only the order of columns matters.

```
str(long)
```

> ```
> Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':    24 obs. of  3 variables:
>  $ Acc_ID  : int  1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 ...
>  $ variable: Ord.factor w/ 12 levels "P1"<"P2"<"P3"<..: 1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4 5 5 ...
>  $ value   : num  -101 -201 102 202 -103 -203 104 204 -105 -205 ...
>  - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr>
> ```

#### Aggregating on variable lengths windows

The OP has requested to compute aggregates on different window sizes all ending with the *anchor point*:

- length 1 which includes just the column of the anchor point
- length 3 which includes the two columns left of the anchor point and the column of the anchor point. This will be skipped in case of anchor points `P1` and `P2`, as there are too few column to complete a set of three.
- length 6 which includes the five columns left of the anchor point and the column of the anchor point. This can be computed only for columns `P6`, `P7`, etc., for which a complete set of six columns is available.
- length 12 which includes all columns and can be computed only for anchor point `P12`.

Although not explicitely mentioned by the OP but it can be concluded from using `rowSums()` that the aggregates have to be computed for each row separately. Here, we assume that `Acc_ID` uniquely identifies each row.

```
library(magrittr)
anchor <- "P5"
lapply(c(1, 3, 6, 12), 
       function(x) {
         long[variable <= anchor, 
              if (x <= .N) 
                .(sum(tail(value, x)), sum(tail(value, x) > 0)) %>% 
                  setNames(sprintf(c("sumcoll%im", "payments%im"), x)),
              by = Acc_ID]
         }
) %>% 
  Reduce(function(x, y) merge(x, y, by = "Acc_ID", all.x = TRUE), .)
```

> ```
>    Acc_ID sumcoll1m payments1m sumcoll3m payments3m
> 1:      1      -105          0      -104          1
> 2:      2      -205          0      -204          1
> ```

#### Explanation

Note that the term *column* is used to refer to data in wide form although the data have been reshaped to long form.

- Line 1: Piping is used to improve readability of code
- Line 2: Set name of anchor column
- Line 3: Loop over window sizes, return results as list
- Line 5: Select only column names left of or equal to anchor column. This works because we are using ordered factor.
- Line 6: Skip if too few data are available for the given window size
- Line 7: Compute aggregates but only for the `x`-last columns using `tail(value, x)`
- Line 8: Name the result appropriately
- Line 9: Group by `Acc_ID`, i.e., row-wise
- Line 12: Merge the list elements repeatedly to get one result data.table

The output of the `lapply()` call before merging the pieces together looks as follows:

> ```
> [[1]]
>    Acc_ID sumcoll1m payments1m
> 1:      1      -105          0
> 2:      2      -205          0
>
> [[2]]
>    Acc_ID sumcoll3m payments3m
> 1:      1      -104          1
> 2:      2      -204          1
>
> [[3]]
> Empty data.table (0 rows) of 1 col: Acc_ID
>
> [[4]]
> Empty data.table (0 rows) of 1 col: Acc_ID
> ```

#### Function call to demonstrate other anchor points

This can be wrapped in a function call for convenience:

```
anchored_aggregate <- function(DT, anchor) {
  library(data.table)
  library(magrittr)
  long <- melt(DT, "Acc_ID")
  long[, variable := as.ordered(variable)]
  lapply(c(1, 3, 6, 12), 
         function(x) {
           long[variable <= anchor, 
                if (x <= .N) 
                  .(sum(tail(value, x)), sum(tail(value, x) > 0)) %>% 
                  setNames(sprintf(c("sumcoll%im", "payments%im"), x)),
                by = Acc_ID]
         }
  ) %>% 
    Reduce(function(x, y) merge(x, y, by = "Acc_ID", all.x = TRUE), .)
  }

anchored_aggregate(DT, "P2")
```

> ```
>    Acc_ID sumcoll1m payments1m
> 1:      1       102          1
> 2:      2       202          1
> ```

```
anchored_aggregate(DT, "P3")
```

> ```
>    Acc_ID sumcoll1m payments1m sumcoll3m payments3m
> 1:      1      -103          0      -102          1
> 2:      2      -203          0      -202          1
> ```

```
anchored_aggregate(DT, "P7")
```

> ```
>    Acc_ID sumcoll1m payments1m sumcoll3m payments3m sumcoll6m payments6m
> 1:      1      -107          0      -106          1        -3          3
> 2:      2      -207          0      -206          1        -3          3
> ```

```
anchored_aggregate(DT, "P12")
```

> ```
>    Acc_ID sumcoll1m payments1m sumcoll3m payments3m sumcoll6m payments6m sumcoll12m payments12m
> 1:      1       112          1       111          2         3          3          6           6
> 2:      2       212          1       211          2         3          3          6           6
> ```

#### Appeding aggregates to original dataset

The OP has asked how the aggregated result can be appended to the original dataset.

This can be accomplished by another join operation, e.g., using the function created above:

```
DT[anchored_aggregate(DT, "P5"), on = "Acc_ID"]
```

> ```
>    Acc_ID   P1  P2   P3  P4   P5  P6   P7  P8   P9 P10  P11 P12 sumcoll1m payments1m sumcoll3m payments3m
> 1:      1 -101 102 -103 104 -105 106 -107 108 -109 110 -111 112      -105          0      -104          1
> 2:      2 -201 202 -203 204 -205 206 -207 208 -209 210 -211 212      -205          0      -204          1
> ```

Comment: Very nice and elegant approach. You definitely proved me wrong. For the final result I will tweak it to handle custom intervals and multiple measure.vars in melt, but the core was just what I wanted. Thank you a ton!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a different approach which works on column data but uses the same trick with ordered factors and `tail()` as [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51836833/3817004). The `.SDcols` parameter is used to select desired columns.

However, it is not necessary to reshape the data from wide to long format. Furthermore, this approach immediately updates `DT` `by reference` so no final join is required.

```
library(data.table)
# prepare sample data set
n_row <- 2
DT <- data.table(Acc_ID = seq_len(n_row))
for (i in 1:12) {
  set(DT, , paste0("P", i), (100*seq_len(n_row) + i) * (-1)^i)
}
# preserve unmodified copy of original dataset
DT0 <- copy(DT)

# create vector of data column names as ordered factor in order of appearance
library(magrittr)
nam_DT <- 
  # omit id column
  colnames(DT)[-1] %>% 
  forcats::fct_inorder(ordered = TRUE)

anchor <- "P5"

# start with fresh copy of original dataset
DT <- copy(DT0)
# loop ovder window sizes
lapply(c(1, 3, 6, 12),
       function(x) {
         # create character vector of columns to process
         cols <- nam_DT[nam_DT <= anchor] %>% 
           tail(x) %>% 
           as.character()
         # skip if too few columns available
         if (length(cols) == x) {
           # compute aggregates and update by reference
           DT[, sprintf(c("sumcoll%im", "payments%im"), x) := 
                .(rowSums(.SD), rowSums(.SD > 0)), .SDcols = cols]
         }
       # suppress intermediate results
       }) %>% invisible()
# print updated dataset
DT[]
```

> ```
>    Acc_ID   P1  P2   P3  P4   P5  P6   P7  P8   P9 P10  P11 P12 sumcoll1m payments1m sumcoll3m payments3m
> 1:      1 -101 102 -103 104 -105 106 -107 108 -109 110 -111 112      -105          0      -104          1
> 2:      2 -201 202 -203 204 -205 206 -207 208 -209 210 -211 212      -205          0      -204          1
> ```

For comparison:

```
DT[anchored_aggregate(DT, "P5"), on = "Acc_ID"]
```

> ```
>    Acc_ID   P1  P2   P3  P4   P5  P6   P7  P8   P9 P10  P11 P12 sumcoll1m payments1m sumcoll3m payments3m
> 1:      1 -101 102 -103 104 -105 106 -107 108 -109 110 -111 112      -105          0      -104          1
> 2:      2 -201 202 -203 204 -205 206 -207 208 -209 210 -211 212      -205          0      -204          1
> ```

Comment: Very neat as well!